# How to see users currently logged in

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm

Dynamics CRM 2011 on premise.

How can I see a list of users currently logged in to the CRM website?

I expect there is a screen somewhere but I can't find it.

Comment: There are 2 ways to audit users access.
Read this article : http://dynamics.co.il/auditing-users-access-crm-2011/

Comment: I guess I should punish my answerers just because Microsoft are deficient so I'll accept this as the answer.

Answer (score 1):

See [this](https://community.dynamics.com/crm/f/117/p/67932/160878.aspx#.UjrpAsZnFrg) link.  There is no way to tell who is "Logged in".  You could however be able to see who has logged in the last X number of hours.

Comment: Surely this is built in?

Comment: @cja.  Nope.  And don't call be shirley. ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can rely on `IIS` Logging, you can find more details here:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/crm/archive/2009/04/08/crm-usage-reporting-unleashed.aspx